# Can we skip the validation of receiver_email in IPN handler?

Tags: php, paypal, payment, recurring

We have recurring payment feature in our project with option to enter **merchant(business account) email details**. we are using HTML form(Not recurring button code) to submit the details to PayPal.

In the IPN handler code, doing following validations if the response from PayPal is VERIFIED

- checking the txn_type for subscr_payment
- verifying txn_id
- verifying the custom field data
- validating receiver_email (validation is done against merchant email details captured)

The problem we are facing is due to validation failure of receiver_email (receiver_email will be the primary email associated with the PayPal business account).

receiver_email  validation is failed because the captured merchant email details has secondary email associated with PayPal business account. 
So my question is whether we can skip the validation of receiver_email?

Answer (score 0):

The validation of receiver_email is actually not compulsory in my integration experience. The receiver_email is contained in the IPN data because some merchants are using different email address within one PayPal account to accept payments from different sites. If you are collecting payments from only one source using one email address, no need to validate the receiver_email at all.

Instead, I would recommend you adding invoice id into your payment data. Validating payments via that data would be more efficient in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.